# how to save into one table sqlite from different class

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

i have one table for saving my data, when user click on button save in sliding menu it will save all variable from different class into one table, this is my sqlite :

```
   public class DBSpaj extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="dbspaj.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;
    int count;
    public DBSpaj(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS master_spaj");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists master_spaj (_id INTEGER,SPAJ_ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                " nama_pp TEXT,"+
                " gelar_pp TEXT,"+
                " ibu_pp TEXT,"+
                " nama_tt TEXT,"+
                " gelar_tt TEXT,"+
                " ibu_tt TEXT"
                ");");

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // no-op, since will not be called until 2nd schema
        // version exists
    }
    public Cursor getSelectMaster_SPAJ() {
        return(getReadableDatabase()
                        .rawQuery("SELECT _id,SPAJ_ID,nama_pp,nama_tt FROM master_spaj ORDER BY SPAJ_ID", null));
    }
    }
//insert pemegang polis 
    public void insertMasterSPAJ(
            String SPAJ_ID,
            String nama_pp,
            String gelar_pp,
            String ibu_pp
            ) {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();   
        cv.put("SPAJ_ID",  SPAJ_ID);
        cv.put("nama_pp", nama_pp);
        cv.put("gelar_pp", gelar_pp);
        cv.put("ibu_pp", ibu_pp);

        getWritableDatabase().insert("master_spaj", null, cv);
    }
//insert tertanggung    
    public void insertTertanggung(
            String SPAJ_ID,
            String nama_tt,
            String gelar_tt
            ) {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("SPAJ_ID",  SPAJ_ID);    
        cv.put("nama_tt",  nama_tt);
        cv.put("gelar_tt",  gelar_tt);

        getWritableDatabase().update("master_spaj", cv, "SPAJ_ID = SPAJ_ID", null);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

this is how i save my strinng from sliding menu

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_save:
             pemegangPolis.onSave();//<--call here
             tertanggungPolis.onSave();
             list_terbaru.setAdapter(new Adapter_Spaj_Terbaru(Menu_SPPAJ.this,model));
             mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(SlidingMenu);
            break; 
}
```

this is my first class's(A.java) code for inserting into table master_spaj :

```
   public class PemegangPolis extends Fragment {
    //Variabel Pemegang Polis edittext
        private EditText nama_pp,gelar_pp,ibu_pp;
    //Textview  
        TextView IdSPAJ;
            Cursor SelectMaster_SPAJ=null;
            Cursor SelectTable_Marital=null;
//          spaj1_adapter adapter=null;
            DBSpaj helper,helper_anak=null;     
private ArrayList<ModelKeluargaPP>ListKeluargaPP;
ModelKeluargaPP ModelKeluarga_pp=null;
//Constructor       
    public PemegangPolis() {

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inisialisasi layout utama
        View polis = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pemegangpolis_layout, container, false);
        IdSPAJ=(TextView)polis.findViewById(R.id.IdSPAJ);
//Inisialisasi edittext dan memanggil focus ketika edittext aktif
        nama_pp=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.nama_pp);
        gelar_pp=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.gelar_pp);
        ibu_pp=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.ibu_pp);

         //Membuat dan memanggil class DBSpaj untuk database        
         helper=new DBSpaj(getActivity());
         helper_anak=new DBSpaj(getActivity());
         SelectMaster_SPAJ=helper.getSelectMaster_SPAJ();
   //return polis dan penutup bundle     
        return polis;
    }


public void onSave(){
    String a= GetTime.getCurrentDate("yyyy.MM.dd.hh.mm.ss.SSS");
    IdSPAJ.setText("AndroidESPAJ"+a);
//  Id_SPAJ.setText("AndroidESPAJ"+a);
    helper.insertMasterSPAJ(
            IdSPAJ.getText().toString(),nama_pp.getText().toString(), gelar_pp.getText().toString(), ibu_pp.getText().toString());

}

//method untuk menampilkan string dari database
public void onRetrieve(int position){
    SelectMaster_SPAJ.moveToPosition(position);
    nama_pp.setText(SelectMaster_SPAJ.getString(SelectMaster_SPAJ.getColumnIndex(SelectMaster_SPAJ.getColumnName(2))));
}
}
```

this is my second class's code (B.java) for updating table :

```
   public class Tertanggung extends Fragment {
    //Variabel Tertanggung edittext
        private EditText nama_tt,gelar_tt,ibu_tt;
    //Textview  
        TextView IdSPAJ_tt;
            Cursor SelectMaster_SPAJ=null;
            Cursor SelectTable_Marital=null;
//          spaj1_adapter adapter=null;
            DBSpaj helper,helper_anak=null;     
private ArrayList<ModelKeluargaPP>ListKeluargaPP;
ModelKeluargaPP ModelKeluarga_tt=null;
//Constructor       
    public PemegangPolis() {

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inisialisasi layout utama
        View polis = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tertanggung, container, false);
        IdSPAJ_tt=(TextView)polis.findViewById(R.id.IdSPAJ_tt);
//Inisialisasi edittext dan memanggil focus ketika edittext aktif
        nama_tt=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.nama_tt);
        gelar_tt=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.gelar_tt);
        ibu_tt=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.ibu_tt);

         //Membuat dan memanggil class DBSpaj untuk database        
         helper=new DBSpaj(getActivity());
         helper_anak=new DBSpaj(getActivity());
         SelectMaster_SPAJ=helper.getSelectMaster_SPAJ();
   //return polis dan penutup bundle     
        return polis;
    }


public void onSave(){
    String a= GetTime.getCurrentDate("yyyy.MM.dd.hh.mm.ss.SSS");
    System.out.println("TES    "+a);
    IdSPAJ_tt.setText("AndroidESPAJ"+a);
    helper.insertTertanggung(IdSPAJ_tt.getText().toString(),nama_tt.getText().toString(),gelar_tt.getText().toString());
    }
}

//method untuk menampilkan string dari database
public void onRetrieve(int position){
    SelectMaster_SPAJ.moveToPosition(position);
    nama_tt.setText(SelectMaster_SPAJ.getString(SelectMaster_SPAJ.getColumnIndex(SelectMaster_SPAJ.getColumnName(2))));
}
}
```

on mysqlite class you can see i have made one function insertMasterSPAJ for inserting data and insertTertanggung for updating data, but when i click on save button in sliding menu, it gives me null on B.java activity. when i try to ignore A.java, B.java can save his data into my table, but when i want to save both of them (A.java and B.java) it gives me java.null.pointer, i have no idea where is my fault... i hope someone understand my problem and help me to solve it, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think your getting NPE in one of these two lines

```
IdSPAJ_tt.setText("AndroidESPAJ"+a);
helper.insertTertanggung(IdSPAJ_tt.getText().toString(),nama_tt.getText().toString(),gelar_tt.getText().toString());
```

If this is the case then make sure

```
1. helper is initialized with helper=new DBSpaj(mContext);
2. all views are referenced using findViewById();
```

Comment: i have initialized helper and all views.... when i put B.java as my first activity, its going fine, but when i put B.java as second activity and A.java as my first activity it give me java.null.pointer on line containing helper.insertTertanggung